# How to get billing details per user or customer in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase Realtime Database you may create multiple databases(database sharding) which allows you to map a specific customer to a database. This enables you to get information per customer, such as billing details, one would assume.

I was wondering how can you get this in Firestore or what would be the workarounds in order to get billings details per customer ?

Thank you!

---

*Note: A customer may have multiple users which are reading/writing data from/to customer specific collections in Firestore.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no per-user accounting or billing in Firestore.  You would have to track and estimate that yourself using some scheme that you invent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I must say it's disappointing that such a great platform does not have something as essential as this, out of the box. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link [firebase pricing][1]

[1]: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/.It will be helpful.Firebase has different plans.You can choose what suits your need.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am aware of their pricing plans. My question was about pricing/user as in user of an application built with Firestore back-end.